# How is the difference between sdf back annotation and spf back annotation?

Tags: synthesis, asic

I'm  a rtl engineer.
I'm confused between the difference of sdf and spf back annotation.
As I know sdf came from STA( PT)  and SPF came from STAR-RC.
So  In my experiance, the sdf used to timing close the netlist without RC elements.
then this netlist to send a PNR team. After extraction RC elements in layout team by starRC. Then finally we once again do post sim with spf(a.k.a back annotation) .

Is this rtl synthesis flow right ? Then where is to do CTS flow?

Comment: What are: SPF, PT, STAR-RC, PNR, CTS, ... Why did you add the FPGA tag? It's an ASIC question, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Post-simulation for timing closure with back annotated timing is done with the post-netlist coming back from the layout tool (different from pre-netlist: inserted buffer, chain reordering,...) with the according SDF file with extracted timing data after layout. 
The SPF containing the physical data can be converted to SDF via a STA tool.